# Redirect To Action using ExceptionFilter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter

I have created an ExceptionFilter:

```
 public class LogException : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
 {

    void IExceptionFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        Utility.Log.LogMe(filterContext.Exception);
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

I want to redirect the user to login page whenever this method is hit.
How can i do that?

Comment: Even if they're already logged in?

Comment: redirect to an action u can take

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's important that your `ExceptionHandled` assignment stays in there, that's a good call, but to redirect too:

```
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary 
                { 
                    { "controller", "Account" }, 
                    { "action", "LogIn" } 
                });
        };
```

Comment: nice, once i test it i'll surely rate your answer thank you